# Spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-data-redis

I get the following in red lines in my log files with JAVA 11.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/C:/Users/lol/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar) to constructor java.math.BigDecimal(java.math.BigInteger,long,int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Also i get the following. is this means something wrong with spring-data-redis

```
      java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
        at io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil.trySetAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:31)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$4.run(PlatformDependent0.java:224)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:218)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:212)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:80)
        at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector.<init>(ResourceLeakDetector.java:171)
        at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector.<init>(ResourceLeakDetector.java:213)
        at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory$DefaultResourceLeakDetectorFactory.newResourceLeakDetector(ResourceLeakDetectorFactory.java:201)
        at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer.<clinit>(HashedWheelTimer.java:89)
        at io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources.<init>(DefaultClientResources.java:173)
        at io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources$Builder.build(DefaultClientResources.java:527)
        at io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources.create(DefaultClientResources.java:237)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.LettuceConnectionConfiguration.lettuceClientResources(LettuceConnectionConfiguration.java:67)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.LettuceConnectionConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91ef855e.CGLIB$lettuceClientResources$1(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.LettuceConnectionConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91ef855e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a54e15a.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.LettuceConnectionConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91ef855e.lettuceClientResources(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
```

followed there is this exception

```
2019-04-12 02:24:42.773 DEBUG 27812 --- [           main] i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0     : jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable

java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @4f18837a
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:558)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6.run(PlatformDependent0.java:334)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:325)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:212)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:80)
    at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector.<init>(ResourceLeakDetector.java:171)
    at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector.<init>(ResourceLeakDetector.java:213)
    at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory$DefaultResourceLeakDetectorFactory.newResourceLeakDetector(ResourceLeakDetectorFactory.java:201)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer.<clinit>(HashedWheelTimer.java:89)
    at io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources.<init>(DefaultClientResources.java:173)
    at io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources$Builder.build(DefaultClientResources.java:527)
    at io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources.create(DefaultClientResources.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.LettuceConnectionConfiguration.lettuceClientResources(LettuceConnectionConfiguration.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.LettuceConnectionConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91ef855e.CGLIB$lettuceClientResources$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.LettuceConnectionConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91ef855e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a54e15a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.LettuceConnectionConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91ef855e.lettuceClientResources(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
```

[image]

Comment: Still getting such traces ... no expert advice ?

Comment: What version of Netty is this using ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer updated the ticket sir

Comment: No comments from experts yet.. :)

Comment: Looks like there is code in Netty trying to hack into the jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe. Code outside of the JDK that needs Unsafe should use sun.misc.Unsafe in the jdk.unsupported module. I realize this doesn't help you here but it's disappointing to see commonly used libraries hacking into internal Unsafe as the separation between the two Unsafe APIs is there to avoid this type of thing.

Answer (score 10):

It's a debug message with stacktrace of Netty package.

I found a solution here: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7817

You need to change your logger level of this package to suppress these warnings.

Add this line below in your logback-spring.xml to suppress all messages.

```
<logger name="io.netty.util" level="ERROR"/>
```